# Word for contents lightly erupting from container

Tags: word-request

I feel like I know this word, but I can't think of it.

Here's the setting. I worked in the school's lab, where I was creating an ester from methane acid + methanol, and I dropped some sulfuric acid into the reaction tube, which made the contents bubble and kind of lightly erupt from the tube. *Erupt* is not the right word because it implies much more volatility than what the eruption really was.

This spillage was somewhere in between a gentle bubble over and volatile eruption. It was kind of like a few pulses of the liquid popping out of the tube, but not all of it erupting out.

Comment: What is "methane acid"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey methane acid is just a lazy way of saying *formic acid*, the latter being the preferred IUPAC name. The systematic IUPAC name however, is methanoic acid.

Comment: I would say some of the liquid **spurted** from the tube.

Answer (score 2):

A phrase for this would be to ***bubble over***. This describes when a liquid bubbles up and spills over the sides of its container, like when a pot of boiling water is left on for too long. This could occur due to a physical or chemical reaction, and describes a relatively gentle overflow of a bubbling liquid, which would be less energetic than an "eruption".

Comment: Good answer but this spillage was somewhere in between a gentle bubble over and volatile eruption. It was kind of like a few pulses of the liquid popping out of the tube, but not all of it erupting out.

Comment: @A.Kvåle So now it's clear that you need more than bubble over and less than volatile eruption. In a single word.

Comment: Send us a video! A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Seriously though, we don't know whether this is froth that remained for while, mere bubbles that burst and disappeared immediately or a new version of Aerographite that you have invented and that persists as a solid.  Why not just say, "gently erupted"? Or "frothed out"

Comment: Unfortunately, the person who videotaped the reaction is currently unavailable. How would one feature a video in a stack exchange post though? @chasly-supportsMonica

Comment: @A. Kvåle - Videos are allowed with the permission of moderators. I believe it's a matter of copyright. If you have the copyright or the copyright owner approves, I imagine it would be allowed.

Comment: EDIT - Maybe I am wrong. I found this https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13375/why-cant-we-add-video-or-even-audio-clips-to-posts

Answer (score 0):

My chemistry teacher often used to adumbrate a test-tube chemical reaction with the word **[effervescence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effervescence)**.

> the property of forming bubbles : the action or process of effervescing

In accordance to the comments on Nuclear Hoagie's reply, I suppose 'ooze out' would befit a reaction which is between that of bubbling out and erupting.